# sass command not found - running service on debian boot

Tags: shell-script, debian, services, init.d

I want to compile sass files remotely on my VPS, so I made this init.d script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# kFreeBSD do not accept scripts as interpreters, using #!/bin/sh and sourcing.
if [ true != "$INIT_D_SCRIPT_SOURCED" ] ; then
    set "$0" "$@"; INIT_D_SCRIPT_SOURCED=true . /lib/init/init-d-script
fi
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          sass
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Script used to compile sass
# Description:       Script used to copile sass and scss files
#            directly, running from boot
### END INIT INFO

# Author: Karol K

DESC="Running sass compiler"
DAEMON=/media/start_sass.sh
```

And here is *start_sass.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
sass --watch /var/www:/var/www --style compressed &
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
When I check *service sass status* I get following:

```
root@Serwer:~# service sass status -l
● sass.service - LSB: Script used to compile sass
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sass)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-08-11 12:14:50 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 9777 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sass stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9785 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sass start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 11 12:14:50 Serwer sass[9785]: /media/start_sass.sh: line 2: sass: command not found
```

System is Debian 8 x64

Comment: I assume that when you run start_sass.sh directly, it does work? If so, it might be a PATH issue. Try giving the sass binary with full path (like /usr/bin/sass, or wherever it is, check with `which sass` in your shell).

Comment: Heh, i'll make it into the answer for future reference :)

Comment: Also I used whereis sass, because I have several files with sass in name and locate gave me very long list... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an issue with the PATH.

Try using the full path in the script, like `/usr/bin/sass`.

Find out where the sass binary is located with `which sass`.

Setting the $PATH variable in the script would also solve it, add this before line before the sass --watch line:

`export PATH=$PATH:/directory/where/sass/is_located/`

where of course the latter part is replaced with the actual directory.